# Programmatically prevent 'You've stumbled upon some vintage web tech'

Tags: html, video-streaming, microsoft-edge

I work for a Video on Demand company. Our current website uses Silverlight to deliver streaming video to customers in IE11. The current website does not support MS Edge.

We are preparing to release a major upgrade to our website that includes a HTML5 player that fully supports IE11 and MS Edge.

The problem is that since our current site uses Silverlight, it has been marked as "vintage" in Edge. **Customers visiting the site in Edge see a screen similar to that shown below**:

[image: You've stumbled upon some vintage web tech]

Testing the new version of our site on the same domain (e.g. test.mydomain.com) has revealed that Edge doesn't recognize the new site as being new at all, and continues to display this message.

Is there a way to programmatically remove a site from whatever list Edge maintains and uses to decide whether or not to display this message?